# Precompiled Azure Function Output to Blob Storage receiving 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-blob-storage

The final output of my C# Precompiled Azure Function is to write to a blob storage as a JSON file. Am I writing to the Blob storage wrong? I hit the breakpoints set on the curly brackets at to the end of the function and it looks like it exits the function. Around 20 seconds later I get the exception:

> Exception while executing function: ServiceBusTriggeredProcessAccepted. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error while handling parameter outboundStringForBlobStorage after function returned:. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

The Azure Function is a Service Bus triggered event. After processing fails the Service Bus queued item auto-increments and retries, a total of 10 times, before it's moved to the dead-letter queue. It should be noted the objects are large enough in size that regular Queue's are too small for them.

```
public class SomeObject
{
    //15 Properties all string and boolean
    public string Attachment{ get; set;}
    public string AnotherProperty{ get; set;}
    public bool IsConditionMet { get; set; }
    //Maybe these aren't needed now since it's blob storage but it's part of the object currently
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
}

[FunctionName("ServiceBusTriggeredProcessAccepted")]
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("accepted")]
 SomeObject someObject,
 TraceWriter log,
 [Blob("accepted-attachments/{Attachment}", FileAccess.Read)] Byte[] blobContent
 , [Blob("accepted-sent/{rand-guid}.json")] out string outboundStringForBlobStorage 
 )
{
    someObject.PartitionKey = "email";
    someObject.RowKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    //Business Logic to execute here
    SomeService.SomeFunctionToSendBlobFile(someObject, blobContent)   
    outboundStringForBlobStorage  = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject);
}
```

I am using:
Azure Functions SDK NuGet Package 1.0.21
Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs 2.2.0
WindowsAzure.ServiceBus 5.0.0
DotNetFramework 4.6.1
Windows Azure Storage Emulator 5.8.0.0
Runtime Version=1.0.11702.0

Does the serialization have to be sanitized somehow? I haven't had to sanitize in the past but the data in that object has changed and that is when the problems started to occur. I would expect that the file to get written to the blob storage immediately or return the exception immediately and not 20 seconds after exiting the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error may have nothing to do with serialization, let's focus on this line.

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

If I understand correctly, the blob input and output both connect with Azure Storage Emulator. There's sth wrong in v5.8 Emulator [failing blob writing](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/801). Install [latest Emulator](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=717179&clcid=0x409)(v5.9 right now) could get rid of the problem.

And also note that `Runtime Version=1.0.11702.0` means the CLI and templates are obsolete, to consume the latest, [force VS to download on startup](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-tooling-feed/wiki/Fixing-Azure-Function-Core-Tools-download-issues-for-Visual-Studio#force-visual-studio-to-download-on-start-up).

1. Ensure `Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools` is the [latest](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/blob/master/VS-AzureTools-ReleaseNotes.md#release-notes), right now it's 15.10.2046. On VS menus> Tools> Extensions and Updates> Updates, Update the extension if it's in the list.
2. Remove `%localappdata%\AzureFunctionsTools` and `%userprofile%\.templateengine` folder.
3. Reopen VS to create a new Function project, wait at the creation dialog, See `Making sure all templates are up to date...`.

   [image]
   After a while, we can see the tip changes as

   [image]
4. Click Refresh to work with the latest template instantly.

Don't forget to update `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` to latest(1.0.24 right now). And we don't need to install `Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs` separately which is referenced by `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` internally.

Once function starts we can see runtime `Version=1.0.12205.0` right now.

Comment: Updating the Azure Storage Emulator did the trick by itself.
I don't have any Extensions and Updates to my Visual Studio Extensions.
I had to run the command line for NuGet Package Manager because the UI wasn't showing any updates. Thanks for noting the version that's updated. I just assumed my UI was working properly.
I didn't have either of the folders or files you mentioned in #2 so if you know why that is that would be helpful.

Comment: @JustinNeff Try to update VS2017 to latest version and try steps above again. If you already work with the latest bits(both VS and Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools), let's use the [PS script](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-tooling-feed/wiki/Fixing-Azure-Function-Core-Tools-download-issues-for-Visual-Studio#execute-an-automated-script) to download  new cli and templates.

Comment: I was able to run the script. I never saw the "Making sure all templates are up to date..."
I updated to 15.9.5 and the Extensions and Updates window reports an error 
 _There was an error deserializing the object of the type Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensionManager.VSGalleryExtensionQuery. Encountered unexpected character '<'._

Comment: @JustinNeff It's expected not to see "Making sure all templates are up to date..." since we have already downloaded the cli using script. I didn't meet the `error deserializing ...` before, did it cause any problem to your function?

Comment: It did not. I does not appear to have affected the function. I will search other posts for solutions to that.
After a the PS Script and a Repair I now have the _%localappdata%\AzureFunctionsTools_ files and the _%userprofile%\.templateengine_
Thanks for the help.